# Goodman MEC961 furnace glowing but not fully igniting. Suspected pressure issues

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, pressure

I have a a Goodman GMEC961004CN. Propane 100,000 BTU two stage furnace. I went to fire it up, and we got lots of air and no heat coming out of it. I checked the board and we had 7 red blinks. The inducer goes off great, the hot surface ignitor is working fine, but when the gas valve engages, it only lights a very small flame at the base of the 1st and 2nd burner. I have taken all of the burners out and cleaned them, cleaned the flame sensor, removed the 1st orifice off of the manifold and made sure that it was clear, I have taken a small hammer and tapped the manifold and the gas control valve while the gas valve is open during the cycle. Now comes the strange part. If while the hot ignitor surface is lit, and the gas valve is open, I blow moderately on the 1st burner, she fires up no problem. I have also gotten it to fire up while I put my finger partially over the 1st burner orifice, which I believe affects the pressure to the burner. When I do get the furnace running by blowing on the hot surface ignitor, I do hear some clicks from the pressure switches. At this point I have reached end of my troubleshooting and would love to hear some more ideas! Thanks in advance. Here is my view. [image]